# Chromecast sender application error when requesting new session

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I have an unpublished custom receiver app, and I am unable to cast to it from my web player sender app in chrome. I do get the receiver "available" message upon initialization of cast api, but when I click on the cast button in player and select the chromecast device from drop down menu in extension, the TV screen goes black and few seconds later I get onError method called with following error:

```
{code: "channel_error", description: "Error: Timeout", details: null}
```

The casting works fine when using default media receiver. Also, I do not see any network traffic coming from chromecast device in my server console log, which means that chromecast is not fetching the receiver application.

I made sure of the following:

- The Chromecast dongle is registered as Cast Receiver device in Cast
  Developer console.
- My macbook has NodeJS server running to serve the
  receiver application and the "Receiver Application URL" in cast
  developer console is correctly pointing to server running on my
  macbook.
- The chromecast and my macbook both are on same network, with
  valid 192.168.x.x IP addresses.

I found another thread discussing this error [Chromecast sample sender application CastHelloText-chrome ends with error when trying to get session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435221/chromecast-sample-sender-application-casthellotext-chrome-ends-with-error-when-t), but the suggestions provided there dont seem to apply to my situation.

Comment: Have you tried to use the Chrome remote debugger to see what is happening with your receiver?

Comment: I did. The <html> node has only <body> node and nothing else. No CSS, no JS, no console logs. Pretty weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this particular error by restarting the chromecast device. I tried it on two separate occasions and both times the issue went away once the device was restarted. I can't explain how it worked, but it did the job. If someone can explain what is the cause of this particular error and why restarting fixes it, I will accept that answer.