# Chrome cast session start fail with error 15

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast-sdk

By referring https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/#6 i have implemented chrome cast in my android app. I was able to cast videos successfully. Experimental setup is not changed(only Receiver Application ID is set to DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID), but now in SessionManagerListener callback i'm getting error 15. Any leads will be helpful. callback flow as given below.

```
            @Override
            public void onSessionStarting(CastSession session) {
            //able to get here
            }


            @Override
            public void onSessionStartFailed(CastSession session, int error) {
               //error =15 
            }
```

**logcat**

```
05-18 19:13:53.757 16733-16733/? E/SdkNetworkParameterUtils: getNetworkOperatorForSubscription [int]
05-18 19:14:04.022 16733-16733/? E/SdkNetworkParameterUtils: getNetworkOperatorForSubscription [int]
05-18 19:14:13.726 685-739/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon: Time-services: Waiting to acceptconnection
05-18 19:14:13.726 859-1019/? E/QC-time-services: Receive Passed == base = 12, unit = 1, operation = 0, result = 0
05-18 19:14:13.734 859-1019/? E/QC-time-services: Receive Passed == base = 13, unit = 1, operation = 0, result = 0
05-18 19:14:13.737 685-739/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon: Time-services: Waiting to acceptconnection
05-18 19:14:13.306 685-1529/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon:Update to modem bit set
05-18 19:14:13.307 31403-31403/? E/QC-time-services: Receive Passed == base = 2, unit = 1, operation = 0, result = 0
05-18 19:14:13.307 685-751/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon:tod_update_ind_cb: Got Update from modem msg_id 40
05-18 19:14:13.307 685-739/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon: Time-services: Waiting to acceptconnection
05-18 19:14:17.437 16733-16733/? E/SdkNetworkParameterUtils: getNetworkOperatorForSubscription [int]
05-18 19:14:21.084 685-739/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon: Time-services: Waiting to acceptconnection
05-18 19:14:21.084 859-1019/? E/QC-time-services: Receive Passed == base = 12, unit = 1, operation = 0, result = 0
05-18 19:14:21.095 859-1019/? E/QC-time-services: Receive Passed == base = 13, unit = 1, operation = 0, result = 0
05-18 19:14:21.095 685-739/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon: Time-services: Waiting to acceptconnection
05-18 19:14:22.343 685-1707/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon:Update to modem bit set
05-18 19:14:22.343 31403-31403/? E/QC-time-services: Receive Passed == base = 2, unit = 1, operation = 0, result = 0
05-18 19:14:22.344 685-751/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon:tod_update_ind_cb: Got Update from modem msg_id 40
05-18 19:14:22.344 685-739/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon: Time-services: Waiting to acceptconnection
05-18 19:14:27.721 16733-16733/? E/SdkNetworkParameterUtils: getNetworkOperatorForSubscription [int]
05-18 19:14:43.076 16733-16733/? E/SdkNetworkParameterUtils: getNetworkOperatorForSubscription [int]
05-18 19:14:50.931 712-712/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 16
05-18 19:14:52.242 1521-1995/? E/IzatSvc_Wiper: W/Num of elements returned by LOWI 5
05-18 19:14:53.095 700-24959/? E/AudioFlinger: open /proc/28333/cmdline error
05-18 19:14:54.964 710-928/? E/QC-time-services: Receive Passed == base = 12, unit = 1, operation = 0, result = 0
05-18 19:14:54.965 685-739/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon: Time-services: Waiting to acceptconnection
05-18 19:14:54.973 710-928/? E/QC-time-services: Receive Passed == base = 13, unit = 1, operation = 0, result = 0
05-18 19:14:54.973 685-739/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon: Time-services: Waiting to acceptconnection
05-18 19:14:56.324 685-1795/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon:Update to modem bit set
05-18 19:14:56.325 31403-31403/? E/QC-time-services: Receive Passed == base = 2, unit = 1, operation = 0, result = 0
05-18 19:14:56.327 685-751/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon:tod_update_ind_cb: Got Update from modem msg_id 40
05-18 19:14:56.327 685-739/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon: Time-services: Waiting to acceptconnection
05-18 19:14:58.048 710-928/? E/QC-time-services: Receive Passed == base = 12, unit = 1, operation = 0, result = 0
05-18 19:14:58.049 685-739/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon: Time-services: Waiting to acceptconnection
05-18 19:14:58.055 710-928/? E/QC-time-services: Receive Passed == base = 13, unit = 1, operation = 0, result = 0
05-18 19:14:58.056 685-739/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon: Time-services: Waiting to acceptconnection
05-18 19:14:58.269 685-1822/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon:Update to modem bit set
05-18 19:14:58.271 685-751/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon:tod_update_ind_cb: Got Update from modem msg_id 40
05-18 19:14:58.271 685-739/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon: Time-services: Waiting to acceptconnection
05-18 19:14:58.272 31403-31403/? E/QC-time-services: Receive Passed == base = 2, unit = 1, operation = 0, result = 0
05-18 19:15:08.403 16733-16733/? E/SdkNetworkParameterUtils: getNetworkOperatorForSubscription [int]
05-18 19:15:13.624 712-712/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 4
```

Comment: post logcat here

Comment: Restart and try again. This might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918880/chromecast-sender-application-error-when-requesting-new-session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/7438776?hl=en-IN

Android TV's Google cast receiver version was at factory version. After updating Google Cast Receiver it solved problem.